# Maven SVN Revision Number

Tags: maven, svn

What is the difference between Status and SpecialStatus?

```
repository = ${prefix.repository}
path = ${prefix.path}
revision = ${prefix.revision}
mixedRevisions = ${prefix.mixedRevisions}
committedRevision = ${prefix.committedRevision}
committedDate = ${prefix.committedDate}
status = ${prefix.status}
specialStatus = ${prefix.specialStatus}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/lvlv/maven-svn-revision-number-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/code/maven_svn_revision_number_plugin/EntryStatusSymbols.java), "status" uses exactly the symbols that an `svn status` command would, while "special status" replaces the punctuation characters with lowercase letters. The '?' for unversioned is replaced with 'u', '!' for missing with 'm', '!' for incomplete with 'i', '~' for obstructed with 'o' and '*' for outdated with 'd'.